# Force SSL on parts of my Joomla site

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, security

In Joomla 2.5 and/or 3, is it possible to enable SSL on certain pages? I am aware of the "Force SSL" option in global configuration, but I have a site with an e-store, and I would like to redirect user to the secure connection when they enter the checkout process. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way I know how is with the Yireo SSL Plugin. I don't think you can force PARTS of your store, but you can force the whole component. You might also want to check to see if your store has an SSL switch (most do).

https://www.yireo.com/software/joomla-extensions/ssl-redirect

Comment: Hi guys, I'm the creator of SSLRedirect, and I though I would drop a note on this: SSLRedirect is able to force SSL upon any page - instead of configuring components or Menu-Items, you can also configure custom URLs and even use regular expressions.

Comment: Is that a newer feature? I recall in the past that I think I could exclude article IDs or something, but couldn't specific certain pages by url. Sounds like it might have been upgraded since I last messed with it.

Answer (score 1):

I second Brian Peat's suggestion of using the Yireo SSL Plugin, but as an alternative you can also achieve this using the .htaccess file (depending on how complex your URL structure is and how many pages you want to redirect).

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^checkout$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect your users to a secure connection if they visit http://yoursite.com/checkout.

Are there any particular reason why you only want SSL on parts of the site? It might be a security issue if sensitive information is sent through a non-secure (HTTP) connection, and then redirected to HTTPS. In that case it's already to late and and the information might have been picked up by someone.

#### Update:

I just noticed that any menu item can be forced to display using SSL:

[image: Secure setting - Joomla 2.5]

[image: Secure setting - Joomla 3]

Answer (score 1):

Both Above answers using the plugin or .htaccess file are valid.(I like the .htaccess myself, more universal) The comment about the Joomla Menu Manager Metadata property may give people a false sense of security: While it does indeed make the LINK go to https, it doesn't force it if you visit the page with regular "http" allowing the data to be sent unencrypted. With security data, I would not relay on the metadata Secure menu if the data really needs to be secure.